# Python socket server do client authentication by using token

Tags: python, twisted

There're basically two issues I'd like to resolve:

1. Client side send query string when initializing the connection to server
2. Server side validate user token in handshake (not after the connection is established and then validate streaming message that contains the token) and set user session accordingly.

I read a article (https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/) that talks about this process implemented in nodejs, just wonder if the same function can be achieved by using python. (Currently I'm doing some research on twisted but haven't found anything similar)

PS: guess it's helpful to demo the use case as well. A user may login to your server over normal http then server will issue him/her an valid accessToken. Then this user may need to establish a socket connection with the server (or some other server), then the server needs to figure out who the user is and validate before establishing the socket connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query strings are part of HTTP URLs.

If you're building a TCP socket server instead of an HTTP server, you don't get URLs—or headers, or anything else out-of-band.* All you get is a stream of data. You need to come up with a protocol for your data that you can fit the token into.

This means the server can't "figure out who the user is and validate before establishing the socket connection". It has to establish the socket connection, read the first message, parse it, validate the token, and then drop or continue the connection. (You can, of course, put up a front-end server that accepts connections, validates them, and then migrates or proxies them to the real back-end server. But *someone* has to accept, read, and parse.)

Note that this is exactly what HTTP does—it can't see the query string until it accepts the connection and reads the first line of data.

Meanwhile, the example you're looking at appears to be using WebSockets. A WebSockets client can't talk to a socket server (well, unless you build a WebSockets server on top of your socket server, or a proxy in front of it) in the first place.

---

<sub>* This isn't *quite* true. You can cram 40 bytes of options into TCP header extensions. But then you have to go below the level people are usually talking about when they say "socket server"—and there's a good chance it won't make it through the internet. Also, TCP *does* have a concept of "out-of-band" data, but that isn't relevant here; you still have to accept the connection and read from it to get an OOB data.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for addressing the key here, I didn't realize the difference between WebSocket and Socket until now. Thus for this use case, besides doing user token authentication after establishing the socket, is there's any other way to authenticate the user over socket communication?

Comment: @Yang: Well, in theory you could try to authenticate based on coming from the same source address… but I think the article you linked to explains why that's a bad idea. You could also build your own TCP-like stream on top of UDP, and make the token part of the stream connection negotiation (see SIP, WebRTC, RTMFP, etc. for examples), but that's a pretty big amount of work for a pretty small benefit if your goal is just "I want exactly what TCP does, except I want to avoid the cost of connection establishment without a token". What real problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm trying to write a game server that separate from a master server (call it authentication server or something), Since user logs into the MS and MS would stored the session (in some cache like redis) and return user an acessToken. Then when user actually connects to the game server, I'd like to use the same token as authentication mechanism from this game server to validate the user and know who he/she is.

Comment: (sorry can't type that long) That's why I found the article interesting in the idea except I'd like to achieve this in socket. One way I can think of is to use a state machine to make sure user needs to pass their accessToken after the socket connection.

Comment: @Yang: Yeah, that works. After the user has connected, start him in a "needs auth" state, and don't switch to the "ready to start real stuff" state until an access token. Most internet protocols that are defined in terms of state machines do things exactly this way. See [IMAP](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) for an example.