# How to add authentication(Username/Password) in Twisted client server application in python?

Tags: python, twisted, tcp

I have managed to built a simple client server application in Twisted that takes the data from the serial port and send it to the server. I want to know how i can add any kind of authentication for accessing the server. Right now anyone with the server IP can send data to the server. Any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can redirect you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048533/python-socket-server-do-client-authentication-by-using-token).

Basically, you need to implement a protocol client & server sides that parses username and password, validates them and keeps the connection open / routes it to a new address, or closes it.
Lower level approaches are also possible, but way more complicated.

Twisted has an [SSL auth built in](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/ssl.html), if it is of any interest to you.